# Balancing a randomization formula in a NetSuite workflow

Tags: workflow, netsuite, formulas

I have a WF where I have created a state that randomizes a field value between 2 specific users. Right now it picks a user every 30 seconds using the formula **to_char({today},'SS') between 00 and 30** . Any ideas on how I would tighten the randomization further? This is because in cases of imports the randomization may be lopsided. Looking to tighten as much and randomly as possible. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this **to_char({today},'SS') % 2 is 1**